# getChildAt() is not working in Custom Viewgroup constructor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-custom-view

I am creating a Compound Like View. Here is **like_layout_1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="12569"
        android:textSize="20px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is **LikeView** class extends **LinearLayout**:

```
public class LikeView extends LinearLayout {

    private ImageView likeImageView;
    private TextView likeCountTextView;

    private boolean isLiked;
    private long likeCount;

    public LikeView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public LikeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }
    public LikeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.like_layout_1, this);

        likeImageView = (ImageView) getChildAt(0);
        likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
    }
}
```

**Inflate Exception** occurs due to these two lines.

```
        likeImageView = (ImageView) getChildAt(0);
        likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
```

Method **getChildAt()** creates the problem because if I comment those two lines no exception occurs and works fine.

NOTE: I don't want to access children using **findByView()** method.

Comment: you may try to get the children inside onFinishInflate method but not sure whether it would work or not. Also there should be a third parameter for the method inflate, try passing true.

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a Compound Like View

Have u tried `[android:drawableLeft][1]` or `[android:drawableRight][2]`

eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="12569"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/like"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now coming to your efforts.

In constructor you cant get child view instance because it wont be initilize before parent is get initialize completely. so check [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method

if you are creating custom view by extending LinearLayout `LikeView`  than in xml layout it should be used with the packagename which contains that `LikeView` custom control class

> NOT LIKE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="12569"
        android:textSize="20px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> IT SHOULD BE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.yourpackage.LikeView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="12569"
        android:textSize="20px" />
</com.yourpackage.LikeView>
```

LikeView.java

> EDITED FOR THE QUESION MORE THN 10-20 CHILD CONTROLS HANDLING

```
    package com.yourpackage;

    import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LikeView extends LinearLayout {

    private ImageView likeImageView;
    private TextView likeCountTextView;

    private boolean isLiked;
    private long likeCount;

    public LikeView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public LikeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

    public LikeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.view.ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View, int,
     * android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
     */
    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        // If the view hierarchy is fixed and limitted thn you can also check
        // with the index

        // but from constructor you wont get instance because first parent will
        // be loaded and child may not be loaded

        int id = child.getId();
        if (id == 0)
            return;
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.seekbar:
            // cast here with seekbar
            break;
        case R.id.txtTouchEventTest:
            likeCountTextView = (TextView) child;
            break;
        case R.id.imageView:
            likeImageView = (ImageView) child;
            break;

        case R.id.show_notification:
            // cast here with button
            break;
        case R.id.hide_notification:
            // cast here with button
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

> EDITED : WITHOUT USING OR IMPORTING ID OR application R in class

Looping and all logic you improvise

```
@Override
    public void addView(View child, int index,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        // If the view hierarchy is fixed and limitted thn you can also check
        // with the index

        // but from constructor you wont get instance because first parent will
        // be loaded and child may not be loaded

        // TO handle it from index

        int size = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                if (TextView.class.isInstance(getChildAt(0)))
                    likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                if (TextView.class.isInstance(getChildAt(1)))
                    likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (SeekBar.class.isInstance(child)) {
                    SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) child;
                }
                break;
            case 3:

                if (ImageView.class.isInstance(child)) {
                    likeImageView = (ImageView) child;
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                if (Button.class.isInstance(child)) {
                    Button btnFirst = (Button) child;
                }

                break;
            case 5:
                if (Button.class.isInstance(child)) {
                    Button btnSecond = (Button) child;
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        // int id = child.getId();
        // if (id == 0)
        // return;
        // switch (id) {
        // case R.id.seekbar:
        // // cast here with seekbar
        // break;
        // case R.id.txtTouchEventTest:
        // likeCountTextView = (TextView) child;
        // break;
        // case R.id.imageView:
        // likeImageView = (ImageView) child;
        // break;
        //
        // case R.id.show_notification:
        // // cast here with button
        // break;
        // case R.id.hide_notification:
        // // cast here with button
        // break;
        // }

    }
```

XML file which i have used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.hiddenbrains.lib.emailutility.LikeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTouchEventTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSecond"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="TextView Second"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:max="100" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hide_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />

</com.hiddenbrains.lib.emailutility.LikeView>
```

Check [this](http://goo.gl/TIy2Fg) for customization of the control

Hope i got your question correctly.. if not pls let me know.

Comment: Are you sure what are you saying ? I am inflating **like_layout_1.xml**. No need to write like **com.yourpackage.LikeView** which view I am inflating. We need to write like **com.yourpackage.LikeView** in which layout we are gonna use that LikeView

Comment: @mahbub.kuet yes .. you need to use addView method  where you can have child view instances ...

Comment: @mahbub.kuet pls check the updated answer with help link

Comment: Still same exception occurs.

Comment: you know findViewById() works in constructor but getChildAt() isn't.

Comment: did you try  updated code of LikeView class .. particularly addView method ? @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {}

Comment: @mahbub.kuet you problem is resolved ? can u pls post the log ?

Comment: hi, right now I am taking references of childs using findById() method. Btw, according to your addView() method if there are 10-20 childs (also with same type, multiple textview) how will your solution work ?
I will post exception log within few hours although I said it is well known Layout Inflate Exception. Right now I need to work on this.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet yes it will work 100% ... what you need to give is to the control is uniqe id ... and apply switch case inside addView

Comment: @mahbub.kuet check the updated answer .. updated LikeView.java class addview method .. :) "EDITED FOR THE QUESION MORE THN 10-20 CHILD CONTROLS HANDLING"

Comment: Okay, you are really doing your best but you know the main reason for posting this question is **without giving unique ID to childs I need to access them using index. this is the real challenge**.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet it is also possible using index and without giving id in xml file u can create instance of the same type of view by index... check the addView method in updated answer and xml file also i have posted... "EDITED : WITHOUT USING OR IMPORTING ID OR application R in class"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69680/discussion-between-mahbub-kuet-and-user1140237).

Comment: @mahbub.kuet so do you found any alternate solution or like that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate()
{
    super.onFinishInflate();
    likeImageView = (ImageView) getChildAt(0);
    likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved as follows:

```
    likeImageView = (ImageView) getChildAt(1);
    likeCountTextView = (TextView) getChildAt(2);
```

Because if you do `getChildAt(0)` and `getChildAt(1)` it inflates ImageView to parent LinearLayout